# Best way to control audio in dual (same LAN) locations from one spot.

Tags: software, speakers, setup, streaming, planning

Currently we have one office that I run music through in this order Pandora-->PC-->amp-->speakers. Pretty simple. 
However, We've added a separate building 300' away that shares the same LAN. I'm trying to figure out a way to be able to stream music to both locations from one controller which is currently a PC but I'm open to a complete setup change. Any good way to make this happen?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've come up with. I'm going to setup a PC-->amp-->speakers setup at both locations separately. I have several old recycled PC's so a cheap alternative here. Then I'm going to use the software AIRFOIL as a server on one PC and a client on the other. There's several other software's that can be used this is just the one I found. This allows me to sync sources, play separately, stream an intercom over both systems, and all kinds of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Sonos](https://www.sonos.com/en/shop). This is a simple way of creating a multiroom streaming service.

If you're a bit technical and think the Sonos is to expensive you can look into something like the [HiFi Berry](https://support.hifiberry.com/hc/en-us/articles/205699981-How-to-build-a-multiroom-audio-system-based-on-Raspberry-Pi-and-Hifiberry). This is much cheaper but requires a bit of work.